# Where can I host many open source projects?

Tags: open-source, hosting, projects

in my spare time I create open source projects which I hosted at google code in the past but apparently google limits the maximum number of projects to 25 which is not what I want.

I have many small projects that I want to share and showcase.

What would be your choice? I know github and sourceforge but I couldn't find information about their limitations so I'm not sure.

Where would you host more than 25 projects?

Comment: Is the number of projects your only criterion?

Comment: I don't care about the dvcs if that's what you mean. Git, subversion, mercurial; I'm ok with all of them. Wiki? Bugtracker? Not my first priority to be honest.

Comment: This question doesn't belong on StackOverflow. It is subjective and possibly to initiate a discussion. Quote from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): `If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.`

Comment: This is objectively answerable and relates to programming tools. So I think it is fine for SO.

Comment: No, this question cannot be objectively answered. Some people might suggest you one provider (http://github), other people might suggest you other provider (http://bitbucket.org). It;s like asking should I choose C# or Java for my next project. You might ask it but not on StackOverflow.

Comment: A list of hosting sites that allow more than 25 open source repositories would be an entirely objective answer to the question. It's a pretty straightforward question, not an invitation to a debate (which is what the subjectivity rule is trying to prevent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- github
- sourceforge

I'm using github a lot more than the second..

Comment: thanks for your reply; I decided to use github :).

Answer (score 4):

My choice would be GitHub.  I don't believe they impose restriction on the number of public repositories you may have, they only ask you to keep under 1Gb each.

Comment: Yep, GitHub is the way to go for free, open-source repos. BitBucket is good too, but I don't believe it's completely "free" (only up to a certain number of developers) or unlimited.

Comment: thanks; I'll use github then; looks developer friendly.